# What is the meaning of く here?

Tags: meaning

```
く‥、邪悪な気が強くなっている‥

く‥‥好むと、好まざるとまわりをまきこみおし流してゆく‥
```

Are these く the same as くっ?

(1) SFX for "damn it" like a silent curse;

(2) Mumble under the breath when in a difficult situation;

(3) When one tries to hold in their voice or is trying to hold back pain or pleasure.

Comment: I believe it means "行く" often used in the same manner as your example, making the snippet "Go ahead and~verb"... hope it helps.

Comment: Probably it's the case.